404 with ngrok and Laravel Valet
I am trying to setup Apple Associated domains, and test some logic around deep linking depending on whether an app is installed or not.
I want to get this setup in local development before I deploy to production.
For development I use Laravel and Valet. Everything is working fine locally hosted as http://pit.test
I have setup a paid ngrok account and have it configured as follows:
version: 3
agent:
  authtoken: ---
  web_allow_hosts:
    - pit.test
    - 127.0.0.1
endpoints:
  - name: pit
    url: xxx.ngrok.io
    upstream:
      url: pit.test

I run ngrok start pit and I see:
Session Status                online                                                                                                                            
Account                       xxx (Plan: Personal)                                                                                                      
Version                       3.18.4                                                                                                                            
Region                        Europe (eu)                                                                                                                       
Latency                       24ms                                                                                                                              
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                             
Forwarding                    https://xxx.ngrok.io -> http://pit.test:80                                                                              

BUT... When I go to https://xxx.ngrok.io I get:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Valet - Not Found</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        404 - Not Found
    </body>
</html>

I’ve tried:

valet restart
looking for logs in ~ /.config/valet/Log. The files are there, but empty

I’m not sure how to debug this further or get it working. Any help greatly appreciated!

My "solution" to this was to stop using Valet and just use artisan serve
